# Hacker Rank Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve a Hacker Rank problem. It's not a difficult problem at all, but for some reason I've been stuck on it all day. Every solution I come up with just doesn't work. I'm certain that all the solutions I came up with were plausible, but the compiler says otherwise.

I've narrowed down the problem, and it seems there's an issue with one line of code. The thing is, I don't know why it's causing the code to fail. I would really appreciate it if someone could enlighten me, thank you.

-- The question requires you to use a for loop, and increment a variable through a range.

The issue seems to be with this specific line :  `cout << letters[n] << "\n";`

If I remove that line and instead write `cout << "hi"`, for example, it works fine. If I put `cout << letters[2]` then it will print the corresponding value, from 'letters'.

Here's the code:

```
int main() {
    
    int a;
    int b;
        
    string letters[] = {"", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    
    cin >> a >> b;
    
    int spaces = a -1;    
    
    for (int n = a; n <= b; n++) {
              
        spaces +=1;

        if (spaces == n) {
            cout << letters[n] << "\n";
        } 
        else if (n > 9 && n%2 == 0) {
            cout << "even\n";
        }
        else {
            cout << "odd\n";
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `n` may be as large as `b`, so are you assured that `b <= 9`?

Comment: This is the sort of issue that can easily be worked out using the debugger to step through the code. If you don't know how to use one, this is the perfect time to learn. A debugger is one of the best tools a programmer has available to them for solving simple logic errors.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is of the form *"why did the online judge reject this code?".*

Comment: "It's not a difficult problem at all, but for some reason I've been stuck on it all day" - hmm :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, `space` is always equal to `n`, so `(spaces == n)` is always true that makes `cout << letters[n] << "\n";` is always to be executed. In the case that b >= length of the array `letters`. `cout << letters[n] << "\n";` is completely not safe. The segmentation fault may come from here. To avoid that, add a condition to the for loop.

```
for (int n = a; n <= b && n < length of the array; n++)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that your variable `letters` is a static array with size `10` but you are accessing more than that index i.e. `9`. When input value of `a` and `b` will be such that `a+b > 10` ( e.g.  a = 5, b = 20 ) then application will crash.

Comment: Thank you, I just found this out, as well. I was able to fix it, by writing this:                    
if (spaces == n && n < 10) {
            cout << letters[n] << "\n";
        }

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution.

```
if (spaces == n && n < 10) {
        cout << letters[n] << "\n";
    }
```